# JQuery check if the next visible element has the same class

Tags: jquery

I have a list of names grouped by Alphabets.
Sample code:

```
<label class="alphabet_selector">A</label>
    <label>Apple</label>
<label class="alphabet_selector">B</label>
    <label>Book</label>
    <label>Baby</label>
<label class="alphabet_selector">H</label>
    <label>Help</label>
    <label>Hello</label>
    <label>How</label>
<label class="alphabet_selector">Z</label>
    <label>Zebra</label>
    <label>Zip</label>
    <label>Zoo</label>
```

assuming that all labels starting with `B` and `H` have `display: none`.
so the `<label class="alphabet_selector">B</label>` and `<label class="alphabet_selector">H</label>` must become hidden. how can I implement this using jQuery?
I tried the following code but it does not work:

```
$(".alphabet_selector").each(function() { 
    if ($(this).next(".alphabet_selector").length == 1){
        $(this).css("display", "none");
    } 
});
```

I think because the `.next` returns labels with `display: none`.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ff4qh0y7/

Comment: `$(this).next(".alphabet_selector:visible")`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. but this does not solve the problem. the problem is that `$(this).next(".alphabet_selector")` does not return an alphabet_selector. but instead returns the first label which has `display: none`

Comment: Your code and question don't make any sense. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm guessing here: `$(this).next(':visible').hasClass('.alphabet_selector')`

Comment: I created a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ff4qh0y7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the next visible element using `nextAll` and `first` and check if it's an `.alphabet_selector` using `is`.

Code:

```
$(".alphabet_selector").each(function() { 
    if ($(this).nextAll(":visible").first().is(".alphabet_selector")){
        $(this).css("display", "none");
    } 
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/0dff337g/